# Change the background position on drag with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background

How do I drag the background image and change its position? Like when you change the position of your cover photo on facebook.

I've searched everywhere but can't find the right one.

Answer (score 0):

On `mousedown`, log the current mouse position. Create a mask, and on that mask:

- On `mousemove`, get the current mouse position and subtract it from the original mouse position. Move the background accordingly
- On `mouseup`, remove the mask and save the new position.

Comment: when I log the current mouse position I'm using e.pageY but the variable changes. How do I set the variable only once?

Comment: Save it in a variable in the mousedown event.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/kentor/jquery-draggable-background), and is as easy as:

```
element.backgroundDraggable()
```

Here you have a [demo](http://kentor.me/jquery-draggable-background/)